# setState for clicked item only in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, checked

In my react app i have multiple checkboxes and I'm toggling the checked state using onClick, it's setting the state but it's changing it for all the checkboxes in the page, i want only the pressed one, here is the code:

**Initial state:**

```
state: {checked: false}
```

**Checkbox:**

```
return boxes.map(box => (
<Checkbox checked={this.state.checked} onClick={() => this.onCheck(box.id)} />
))
```

**Function:**

```
onCheck(id) { this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }); }
```

Comment: you need a unique piece of info in your state object ... for each checkbox for that to work properly ... `state = { checkBox1Checked: false, checkBox2Checked: false, ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you'll have to have one state variable for each checkbox. For simplicity, let's put all booleans defining whether the n-th checkbox has been checked into a single array.

You can write a minimal component like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { boxes: [{id: 10}, {id: 20}] };
    this.state.checked = this.state.boxes.map(() => false);
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
  }
  onCheck(id) {
    let index = this.state.boxes.findIndex(box => box.id==id);
    this.setState({
      checked: this.state.checked.map((c,i) => i==index ? !c : c)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
      {this.state.boxes.map((box,i) => (
        <input
          key={box.id}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.checked[i]}
          onChange={() => this.onCheck(box.id)}
        />
      ))}
      <pre>this.state = {JSON.stringify(this.state,null,2)}</pre>
    </div>);
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: but i need to use the id why did you remove it? and the boxes are coming from the state `boxes: []`

Comment: *"I need to use the ID"* well I couldn't guess it, you didn't included an [mcve]

Comment: Done! Is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

It's changing all of the checkboxes because all of the checkboxes are referring to the same variable in state. You could store their ids in an array:

```
state: {
  checkedIdArray: []
}
```

Then check if the current box's id is in the array to determine whether it is checked:

```
<Checkbox
  key={box.id}
  checked={this.state.checkedIdArray.includes[box.id]}
  onClick={() => this.onCheck(box.id)}
/>
```

Finally, your onCheck() method would look something like this:

```
onCheck(id) {
  if (this.state.checkedIdArray.includes(id)) {
    this.setState({
      checkedIdArray: this.state.checkedIdArray.filter((val) => val !== id)
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      checkedIdArray: [...this.state.checkedIdArray, id]
    });
  }
}
```

Haven't tested or anything but something like this should get you where you want to go.